# Restrict to only 3 orders per 30 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in Rails that has a specific sales model. I need to allow a user to create only 3 orders per 30 days. So if users creates one order then to permit two more orders within 30 days. 30 days counter should start upon the creation of a first order.
And after 30 days to reset a counter for ordering, where user is again capable to create 3 orders...

Right now, once each order is created it is saved to the database and unlimited amount of orders are available.

I'm not sure how can I achieve this and restrict a current_user from creating more than 3 orders per 30 days. 
I also want to show an error notice that more than 3 orders are not possible per 30 days.

I have products, orders, users and each have models and controllers. Orders also are capable of having many statuses like "completed", "processing",etc.
I'm using standard Devise authentication.

order_items_controller:

```
def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
  end
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :order
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :omniauthable, :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

order_item.rb:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

order_status.rb

```
class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    belongs_to :user
end
```

form_view.html.erb for each order item

```
 <%= form_for OrderItem.new, remote: true do |f| %>


        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, value: 1, min: 1 %>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure that you want to order this item for current cycle?'}, class: "btn btn-default black-background white" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just create a function within the user class that checks, before each order is placed, how many orders the customer has placed within the last 30 days? And if the number of orders are three you send the user to a count down page or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is adding a boolean flag to your Order to indicate it's "starting chain" order (one that starts 30 days counter). Order with this flag set to true will start 30 days counter, while with false flag will be "regular" orders.

Then upon creation (in `def create`) you do something like this:

```
last_30_days_orders = Order
  .where("user_id = ? AND created_at > ?", current_user.id, DateTime.now - 30)

if last_30_days_orders.any? {|order| order.starting_chain? }
  # there was a starting chain order in last 30 days
  if last_30_days_orders.length >= 3
    # reject new order - already 3 orders in chain
    ...
  else
    # there is a chain and it has less then 3 orders yet - ready to go
    @order.starting_chain = false
    # proceed with saving
    ...
  end
else # no orders within 30 days, or starting_chain order was more then 30 days ago 
   # => new period starts
   @order.starting_chain = true
   # proceed with saving
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Here is what I did: I added a new boolean column to orders and by default it has been set to true. Then in the submit form I added a hidden field <%= f.hidden_field :starting_chain, value: true %>. I added the code you wrote here to my def create action in order_items_controller but it's not working I'm still able to create unlimited orders for each user.. I can also see that starting_chain is passing with "t"..

Comment: There should be created_at > DateTime.Now - 30 condition in where